The expression "На крючок!"
In Подросток by Dostoevsky we have:

Сам давал по десяти и по двадцати пяти просителям. На крючок!

I don't understand the expression "На крючок!". My guess (with the context) is that the narrator emphasizes that he is giving much money, but I don't relate it with the word крючок. What does it mean exactly? Is it used nowadays?

I don't know for sure, as I'm not a native speaker, so I'm not using the Answer function, but the Comment function. Looking at https://www.multitran.com/m.exe?s=%D0%9F%D0%9E%D0%9F%D0%90%D0%A1%D0%A2%D0%AC%D0%A1%D0%AF+%D0%9D%D0%90+%D0%9A%D0%A0%D0%AE%D0%A7%D0%9E%D0%9A&l1=2&l2=1, попасться на крючок means to take the bait, to fall for it. I like Multitran. It sorts more problems than other dictionaries.

It mean he is asking for money for alcohol. A cup (чарка) hangs on a hook (крючок) next to a wine barrel for example, and people can pay a bit of money to drink. So it doesn't mean a lot of money either since he implies giving 20-25 kopecks to similar paupers, and within the context of main character talking about giving 300 roubles to someone earlier in the story.

Thank you very much! Now I see: "На крючок!" is said by the бывший поручик, while I thought it was a complement of the  previous sentence.
